# why do we rather check condition for false than for true

Tags: if-statement, boolean

By reading many tutorials out here, I noticed that mostly, if a condition is checked, like in a if/else, people would rather check first if a condition is false than if it's true
like

```
if(condition is false){

 //stop what you're trying

} else {

 //do what I want to be done

}
```

Anyone has a good explanation?

ps: I asked this question without a specific programming language declaration as I saw this practise in many different languages

Comment: Actually language *can* matter, since there are some languages which allows users to overload the `!` operator for some types and expressions. It's also not a generic all-languages-have-it kind of operator. Finally, unless the operator is overloaded it's just a matter of personal preference which makes this very subjective.

Comment: thanks, I deleted the ! operator

Answer (score 0):

OK, after asking my collegues, I got this answer:

False is more reliable because it is more obvious.

A defintition can be false, or not false.

In Programming, 0 is false, whereas 1 is true, but 2 would also be true.

That's why we'd rather check for the absolute false, than for all the eventually not false cases.